# return last inserted id sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

How could I send the last inserted id when creating a new entry in sequlize?

Currently this is the model way of creating a new value:

```
function post( request, response ) {

    models.xxx.create( {

            field1: request.body.field1,
            field2: request.body.field2

        } )
        .then( function ( x ) {

            //x = 0 || 1;
            response.json( x );
            //What I would like to send is the `id` of the new row

        } );

}
```

Is that possible with sequelize, or do I have to query the table?

Comment: x should be your newly created row so it has the id no ? x.getId()

Comment: I don't know why, but when I was testing i just saw a `[1]` logged, now i see the full object, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the promise function returns the newly created row, but for some reason I could only see `[1]` at my console, now I see the object.

```
.then( function ( x ) {

    //x = new created row
    response.json( x );

} );
```

Comment: So when you used `create`, it returned the autoincremented primary key on the table? Sequelize keeps returning `'0'` for all my inserts.

Comment: Did you add `autoIncrement: true` to your id attribute

Answer (score 4):

I am using MSSQL dialect and the return result is a row of new created data. Access object key "id" will show you the last increment id used.

```
.then( function ( x ) {

    //x = new created row
    response.json( x.id );

} );
```

Comment: Works for MySQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5499#issuecomment-480528090

use @@IDENTITY into a raw SELECT query

Comment: you can also use `.then (anything => {sequelize.query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS lastId', {type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
        .then(id => {res.json({id: id[0].lastId}) })`

Comment: I edited the github answer, now you have a standard res.json() to understand how. `router.post("/link", (req, res) => { const rowData = { autoincrementId: req.body.id, name: req.body.name } yourModel.create(rowData) .then(row => { sequelize.query('SELECT @@IDENTITY', {type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}) .then(id => console.log(id); res.json({id: id[0]['@@IDENTITY'] }) })); ...`